# ubuntu: virtual box, host can only ping guest, cannot access outside world

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox 'slackware 14' image that works fine in Opensuse 13.2, Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, I just export and inport it, and change the network adapter. On Ubuntu however, things not just works, from slackware I could ping only the host and but not any no other devices on the network. On the Ubuntu quest however I have access to the internet and all other devices on the network. The network is configured as 'bridge adapter', as on all other VirtualBox scenarios.

> > ### Virtualbox 4.3.28
> >
> > On Ubuntu I use the network manager, and enabled ssh (as this also was disabled on standard install).
> >
> > ### Network manager (Wired connection)
>
> Manual
>
> > 192.168.2.150 Mask 255.255.255.0 Gw 192.168.2.222
> >     DNS 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
> >     Searh Domain creat
> >     route (none)
>
> ### IpTables produce this
>
> gerrie@Yoga-15:~$ sudo iptables -L
>   [sudo] password for gerrie: 
>   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>
> ### route -n produce
>
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>      0.0.0.0         192.168.2.222   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
>      192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
>
> ### I even tried
>
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

```
Every body says you just need 'bridge adapter' on virtualbox.

What must still be done to enable the virtual machine (192.168.2.171) to ping say the gateway at 192.168.2.222? I tried quite a few
```

Answer (score 0):

"You just need bridge adapter"

Shutdown your VM. In the settings for the machine's Network Adapter, make sure Attached To: "Bridged Adapter" is selected. And also in Name: make sure the name of your WAN facing adapter is selected (ie, eth0, eth1, or whatever yours is).

Comment: I do have bridge adapter settings, but it works as 'host only' , see ""The network is configured as 'bridge adapter', as on all other VirtualBox scenarios. This is what is so strange.. it just does not work on Ubuntu. I was ab le to use this same set-up on all other host set-ups but UBUNTU. >> ## Adapter Network settings.. >> Enable ticked, Attach to Bridge Adapterm Name eth0 (the only one available),Advance Intel Pro, Promiscuous Deny, Cable Connected ticked.It must be something else.